# Can't load app with firebase onto my iPhone, Xcode 12, iOS 14

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

As soon as I install Firebase in my project, my app can no longer load onto my iPhone 11 Pro. I get a popup that says ”Unable to install ‘app name’”. I have tried installing with SPM, Cocoapods, Carthage and manual installation. I don’t even have to call FirebaseApp.configure(), just its very presence triggers this.

I tried a brand new project that I built just to narrow down the problem. The deployment Info is for iOS 14.0 on iPhone and iPad

I am installing Firebase 7.11.1 in SPM, not sure what version I’m getting in the other methods. My iPhone is at iOS 14.5 and the compile is with Xcode 12.5 on an M1 MacMini with macOS 11.3.

I also tried it on a 2019 27” iMac running macOS 11.2.3, Xcode 12.4. I got the same results.

Is this just a Firebase problem? Or is there something else that I’m just not seeing?

The details of the failure are as follow:

**Details**

```
Unable to install "TheCherishingHeart"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402652994
--
This application’s application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402652994
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE80000BE)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011ab4de98 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011ab89898 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 160
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001044b3644 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011ab895e4 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1316
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000112e57d40 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.294 + 2928
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001045dc814 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001045de238 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 680
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001985d20f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001985d3e90 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001985db678 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 620
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001985dc274 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 404
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001985e6b44 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019877eff8 _pthread_wqthread + 276
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019877dd30 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.3 (Build 20E232)
Xcode 12.5 (18205) (Build 12E262)
Timestamp: 2021-04-30T10:15:51-04:00
```

Comment: Nothing specific to Firebase here Peter. Check out the general guidance on this error. Seems to be related to the app id prefix.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the clue I needed. I have provisioned it correctly and that definitely was the problem